# vb.net Is this reflection

Tags: javascript, json, reflection, com

I am building an app and I would like to read various properties from a file and dynamically create classes for them. The object being to use one set of basic code and change a target by selecting the file to create the classes to operate on.  I hope I am defining my objective properly. I can bone up on reflection if I need to, I just don't want to fly off on a fruitless tangent. Is C# as better platform for this?

Thanks

Dean Geary

Comment: Hi, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first